# Shared Hosting Mysql Quota

Tags: mysql, quota

Since MySql does not have a built in quota tool, I wonder how the Big Companies like Daddy and Gator and so on manage their limitations for users?

I was thinking about to use some kind of script to check if the db is over a certain size, but if someone imports a huge thing in, then what? Is there a limitations for how big dump can be imported in?

Comment: you don't limit the import, you run a job occasionally, that takes suitable action.

Comment: And if someone imports a dump over 1 GB? Just let them do it? When the script runs, it will get there.... I know the script has to run from cron constantly.

Comment: I have imported databases which are too big for the shared service I was using only to have them limited when the scrip runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's one of two methods:

1) Limit the disk space using a filesystem quota for the folder where the database file is hosted. This is easily accomplished using `/home` directories for each user and symbolic links to where MySQL looks for the database files.

2) A cron script runs every x minutes that checks for table sizes and revokes CREATE/INSERT statements for databases over the limit.

The second method won't prevent short-term abuse, but you can minimize impact by ensuring there's plenty of extra space and have policies in place to discourage abuse.

Comment: With Method #1 Have to configure quota for the disk for each folder containing mysql db files. Method #2 would allow users to upload gigantic databases. Is there a way to limit in mysql how big dump file can be imported? Like dump can not be larger than 1 GB ? To upload that over phpmyadmin would be hard anyway, but still... Is there such an option? Because with that It can be useful with the cron script.

Comment: Normally, phpmyadmin is limited by the PHP upload settings so it'd be difficult to accomplish anyway. `max_packet_size` in mysql's config can be tuned too.

Comment: @NathanC Can you write an example for method 1 since symbolic link from database folder to quoted directory will not include the size.